# Verbo-nominal complexes

Tags: verbs, phrases

I got this one question for my English exam but I don´t understand what is meant by those expressions. Please could someone explain to me what the expression verbo-nominal complexes stands for.

Verb and the structure of verb phrase. (Kinds of complementation and transitivity, copular Complementation – **verbo-nominal complexes**, infinitives and ing-forms.

Comment: The term you highlight in bold is not used in straightforward traditional descriptive grammar. Which exam are you referring to and in which country to you live?

Comment: It is linguistic exam - this question is from the "syntax" part

Comment: Have you asked your teacher?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretched_verbA stretched verb is a complex predicate composed of a light verb and an eventive noun. An example is the English phrase "take a bite out of", which is semantically similar to the simple verb "bite". The concept has been used in studies of German and English.[1] Other names for a stretched verb include "supported verb", "expanded predicate", "verbo-nominal phrase", and "delexical verb combination". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretched_verb I have never seen this term used in ELL.

Answer (score 1):

A verbo-nominal phrase (or complex) is sometimes called a stretched verb. A stretched verb is a complex predicate composed of a light verb and an eventive noun. An example is the "take a bite out of", which is semantically similar to the simple verb "bite". Other names for a stretched verb include "supported verb", "expanded predicate", and "delexical verb combination".

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/47112851_A_course_in_English_syntax_syllabi_for_the_lectures_examples_and_exercises (page 34)